# Improving a "tumbleweed" question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, asking-questions

So I searched for this on Meta and the regular site, and read the FAQs.  The suggestions were to edit the question to bump it, or offer a bounty.

I don't have enough rep to offer a bounty, and I don't currently have anything of substance to add. I've done a ton of research (hours and hours on MSDN, this website, other coding forums, etc) and have landed at a point where I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I already edited the question once with a minor change, but I don't want to "abuse" the system by continually bumping with non-valuable edits, as this seems to be frowned upon.

I'm not sure if no-one is interested or if no-one has the answer, but I would hope for at least a comment or two saying "can't be done" or something like that if that is indeed the case.

My current workaround sucks, and I'd really like to figure out this little piece of the project to get everything working properly.

Any advice?

Comment: In a similar situation, I spent a couple of days camped out on a tag where I had some skills, answering questions, and accumulated enough reputation to offer a bounty.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: [Is this the question you're asking about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810426/createdialog-in-vba-to-create-modeless-dialog-box) It could help you to have some context. Apart from that... It looks like it could still use some editing to me, but that's mostly formatting as far as I can tell. (And "Thanks" is generally discouraged as fluff in posts. I know it's polite, but it's unnecessary here.)

Comment: It semi-worked. I got more attention as a result of the bounty, which is all you can count on, but no completely satisfactory answer. There may simply be no way of doing what I wanted to do.

Comment: I suggested an edit to help with the formatting on your question. Feel free to reject, or rollback if it is accepted, if you disagree with it.

Comment: Hi, yes that is the question. I made some slight edits this afternoon to formatting.  I'll review yours now.

Comment: Since you're newer, and looking at your replies on this and the SO question, I'll give you a pro-tip: If you want to respond to someone's comment and have them notified, put `@username` in the comment, where username is their displayed username. For instance, to ping you I would type @CBRF23. Note that this only works if the user has already commented OR has edited that post. You don't have to ping the author of a question/answer as they'll be notified of comments on their posts automatically.

Comment: @Kendra, that is a good tip, I did not know about that.  I also appreciate your help with getting the original question noticed. Finally have some dialog going, which is a good start.  I realize saying "thanks" maybe fluff, but thanks ;)

Comment: Well, there's now a bounty. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @DavidThomas  1) Thanks for the help 2) Someone suggested an answer that it cannot be done, which seems very knowledgeable and does address some questions I had in the back of my mind about some of the winAPI programming.  Now, if I mark this as the answer - do they get your bounty?  Should they?  I'm not sure on the etiquette here.

Comment: @CBRF23 only the person who posted a bounty chooses who gets it - so you can accept any answer and they could choose to reward another answer or none at all if they want. (p.s. looks like asking how to solve the problem on meta solved the problem :D )

Comment: @user568458: and that's partially the reason for the bounty, I felt the question was good enough to 'deserve' an answer, and also as a 'reward' (I'm quoting that word because it reads as more patronising than I'd like) for the OP for not only asking a good question, but for using Meta intelligently (and not ranting about no (good) answer). That said, I do wish there'd been a "this is how it can be done" answer, rather than Hans' "yeah, that can't be done." Still: the answer's good, and (based on Hans' knowledge and reputation) seems correct. So, that's good.

Comment: @CBRF23: you're welcome! As for the bounty, I'm not sure what happens with bounties if they're awarded to a community wiki-answer. But we may all find out, later in the week! :)

Comment: @DavidThomas bounties awarded to CW answers are still awarded (to the original author)

Comment: @Benjamin: thanks! I'd, obviously I suppose, wondered about that :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A question like yours produces a bit of a catch-22 situation: it's a good question, well phrased, clear and unambiguous, and you're trying to do something that's not mundane. But what's working against you is that your answer isn't *easy*, so a lot of people will tend to skip over it and not answer. When you've spent a fair amount of time researching prior to asking you lower your odds of getting a quick profitable answer, you've upped the ante for participation in your question.

There is no quick solution to this problem - I've experienced it a couple of times myself. Sometimes the time of day that you post can make a difference - you want to get a time where some reasonably skilled people are likely to be looking at questions, but not a time where so many questions are arriving that yours quickly slides right down the list. But the other thing that really gets people's attention is a decent bounty - people are far more likely to put some time aside and have a decent crack at your question if there are a decent amount of magical points on offer.

Do be circumspect with the amount of editing you do to nudge the question - it can quickly become counter productive if someone notices and gives you a down vote for it.

Comment: that is exactly why I posted here - I didn't want to draw negative attention to the question by bumping it with non-valuable edits.

Comment: Basically the advice in this answser is to gain enough reputation by helping others in order to be able to put a big enough bounty on your own questions.

Comment: Yes, help others, garner rep and offer a bounty. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: @superluminary There are some. Like posting a meta question ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP Yes, this is true :)

Comment: @slugster, Why will *" the time of day that you post [the question]"* make a difference? Surely when he edit the question to put in more details, the "bump" from the edit is as bumpy as a new question right?

Comment: @Pacerier It depends on which view the viewers are using when they look for questions to answer. For example, editing a question would bump it on the *active* and possibly the *interesting* queues, but not the *newest* queue.

Comment: @slugster, But would it bump it on the "main page" queue? That seems to be the most important....

Answer (score -1):

What you should do in a case like this, it seems, is post a question on Meta...

Someone kind will stick a +500 bounty on it, and you'll get lots of views, enough upvotes for a silver badge*, and some decent answers!

---

*extrapolating forward by a few hours

Comment: Exploiting meta users...

Comment: I had no intention of "exploiting" anyone - I just wanted to know what to do without using meaningless edits to bump.  It seems the best path is to try to build reputation and offer a bounty when you can.  DavidThomas was kind enough to do so on my question, and it is obvious that bounty surely does bring a lot more attention to a question!

Comment: @CBRF23 absolutely. My answer was entirely tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @chiastic-security - I should have clarified, I was just responding to Unihedron's comment.   Haha.